# Using HTML in Span title attribute

Tags: html

Is it possible to have HTML tags not get escaped in a span title attribute?

Ex:

```
<span title="Non-italicized text<i>Some italicized text</i>">for this span</span>
```

Comment: what?
I don't understand don't you mean:

<span><i>Some italicized text</i></span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The title attribute only outputs text it does not render html.

Comment: You can somewhat style a tooltip with Bootstrap attributes.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/  ... https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp